# ActionBlock or TransformBlock when just modifying TInput and not creating a different TOutput?

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

When daisy chaining multiple blocks that modify the same `TInput` elements, I can either use `ActionBlock<TInput>` or `TransformBlock<TInput,TInput>`, the difference being that the Transform's delegate would return the same (but modified element) while the Action delegate wouldn't return anything, it would just modify the input element.

Both work, and I suppose both make some sense semantically, but I'm assuming only one of those is the intended way.

If I had to guess, I'd say it's Action because when returning the same elements, it's not really a transformation. But if I had to guess for more pragmatic reasons, I'd say Transform, because if I'm daisy chaining these blocks Transform seems to allow me to post a "processed" element straight to the next block, not sure how I could enforce that with Action.

Comment: One thought: do you *have* to modify the element in-place rather than transforming it? I would expect the transformation approach to be easier to diagnose for all the normal immutability benefit reasons.

Comment: I guess I could "enrich" my architecture a little by creating different "modified" classes that implement or otherwise encapsulate the original class. For instance, let's say the element I'm modifying is of type `Bimbo`, and the action consists of assigning a category. I could instead create a new class "ClassifiedBimbo" and my lambda would be like `public ClassifiedBimbo ClassifyBimbo(Bimbo bimbo)`.

Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a good idea to me. If you can embrace immutability, data pipelines end up being simpler to work with in my experience - and clearer, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to modify the object in your block and then work with it in another block, then the only correct option is to use a `TransformBlock`. I'd say that it is a transformation: the resulting object has the same identity as the original, but it was modified (or “transformed”) in the block.

`ActionBlock` is most commonly used as the end of a pipeline, its final step. That's not what you want here, so `ActionBlock` is not appropriate.